# Delete specific contact in Contact Book project on Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to delete one specific contact from a list of dictionaries. But I have the next error:return self.contacts.remove(x) ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
The find contact function works, I try something similar in delete function but it does not work

```
class Contact_book:
    contacts = []

    def save_contact(self, name, address, phone, email):
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.phone = int(phone)
        self.email = email
        return self.contacts.append({'Name' : self.name, 'Address' : self.address ,
                                     'Phone' : self.phone, 'E-mail' : self.email})
    def find_contact(self, name):
        self.name = name
        return print([self.contact for self.contact in self.contacts if self.contact['Name'] == name])
    def delete_contact(self, name_to_delete):
        self.name_to_delete = name_to_delete
        x = [self.contact for self.contact in self.contacts if self.contact['Name'] == name_to_delete]
        return self.contacts.remove(x)

celular = Contact_book()
celular.save_contact('Chris', 'Bogota', 319211, 'cha@me.com')
celular.find_contact('Chris')
celular.delete_contact('Chris')
```

Comment: `x` is a list not a dictionary. You could do `self.contacts.remove(x[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is a list not a dictionary. You could do `self.contacts.remove(x[0])`. Another option:

```
def delete_contact(self, name_to_delete):
    x = next((item for item in self.contacts if item["Name"] == name_to_delete), None)
    if x: self.contacts.remove(x)
```